# Parse JSON from URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to parse json retrieved from url in jsp. My url is giving response in json format and now i want to call it in my html page.

My url is giving response as

```
{"status":1,"msg":"List of Rooms","id":["1","2","3"],"name":["php","Java","myroom4"]}
```

I am not able to understand what is going wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $.get('http:....', function(data, textStatus) {
        alert('Status is '+textStatus);
        alert('JSON data string is: '+data);

        var myJson = JSON.parse(data);
        var myJson = JSON.parse(textStatus);
        var myJsonObj = jsonParse(myJson);

        alert(myJsonObj.msg); 


        }, 'text');

</script>
```

My url is giving response as

```
{"status":1,"msg":"List of Rooms","id":["1","2","3"],"name":["php","Java","myroom4"]}
```

Comment: Do you get an error ? What is it ?

Comment: no i am not getting any error. actually i am not getting any response only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no need of parsing(JSON.parse)..you can directly say `data.msg` to get the required response as ajax responses can be directly in the form of JSON objects...

if its not two dimensional

```
$.getJSON(
          "http....url",
          function(data){

              alert(data.msg);

              });
```

this should work for you. Tested it here.

Comment: can you please be a bit brief? please write the code if possible

Comment: <body>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $.getJSON('http....', function(data, textStatus) {
   
        alert('Status is '+textStatus);
        alert('JSON data string is: '+data);
   
        var myJson = JSON.parse(data);
        var myJsonObj = jsonParse(myJson);
  
        alert(myJsonObj.msg); 
  
//      alert(data.msg); 

        var x=document.getElementById("Roomcount");
        alert(x.innerHTML);
        }, 'text');
  </script>
<div id="Roomcount"></div>
</body>                        This is my code on which i am working

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>  
    <title>ABC</title>
</head>
        
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $.getJson('http:....', function(data, textStatus) {
        alert('Status is '+textStatus);
        alert('JSON data string is: '+data);

        alert(data.msg); 


        }, 'text');

</script>

<body>
<div id="Roomcount"></div>
</body>
</html>. This is also is not working.

Comment: edited the answer...again...check out..this should work and you may need to add JQuery to make it work...

Comment: what is your output. Can you send me snapshot or something.? I embedded this script in my html page but can not get anything on browser.

Comment: or can we show the entire response in browser and not any specific part of json response ?

Comment: i am not clear what you meant by entire response....it depends on your requirement....

Comment: The url i am using gives a response in JSON. Now I want to display this response on browser in an html page. What should i do?

Comment: there are no .js files till now called. Are there any by deafault .js files that need to be called?

Comment: Further there is no .json file too attached. I just have a url on which i have to work.